# CSS in Wordpress stops working when resizing the browser

Tags: css, wordpress

So to keep the story short - I was trying to integrate a wordpress blog into my website, which works fine.
But I wanted it to look just like my other pages, so I created a custom theme. That also works fine...but only as long as you don't
rescale your browser window.

Once it hits the 'mobile' size all the CSS styling I have just disappears...I have no clue why. I used the same CSS that I used for my other pages and they work perfectly fine.

Anyway you can check it for yourself here http://arturzima.com/news/

FOUND THE PROBLEM:
This little guy right here in the head tag:  media="all and (min-width: 36.875em)"

Comment: I don't get any styling, desktop or mobile, when I view the site.

Comment: There is no style at all in desktop as well

Comment: are you sure? I mean I'm getting it. Maybe it was a temporary server issue, happened earlier on today

Comment: Looks like you don't have a media query which covers mobile sizes

Comment: I do - it works on other pages. In fact, I noticed it works on the news section just before it breaks, if you scale your window slowly you might be able to see it

Comment: Okay now I see what you mean, I don't see any styling either now...

Comment: It is a server issue, I'll to contact my host

Comment: Well it seems to be working only on Chrome for some strange reason, can you guys check please?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code errors; you have broken comments, broken closing tags, etc. Those errors are part of the problem with display.

See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  arturzima.com news  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//arturzima.com/news/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Start fixing the code errors and revalidate.

Comment: I fixed all the errors however the problem still exists.